# angularjs $window.onclick performs better than ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, onclick, angularjs-ng-click

I had a scenario where I have to make some alterations in localstorage as well as in some other data of the controller, this logic was supposed to be done on click of anywhere in whole page. This code was supposed to close all colorpickers if click was done anywhere on the body but not on the colorpicker button, but if clicked on colorpicker button then close all others colorpickers and open only the respective one. First I tried using ng-click which was working okay but the pace of closing all colorpickers and opening of respective one was very slow.

Note that I tried using `$scope.$apply();` but that didn't work but instead it started giving me error that angularjs digestion is already in progress. Then I used  `$window.onclick` which worked perfectly and the pace of colorpickers closing and opening was also very fine. I am wondering why `$window.onclick` worked better than `ng-click`. That function is as follows

```
$window.onclick = function (e) {
        var labels = getAllLabels(vm.allData);
        if (!e.target.classList.contains('color-picker-button') || e.target.classList.contains('color-picker-popup') || e.target.classList.contains('buttons-popup-charts')) {
            for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                labels[i].isOpen = false;
                localStorageService.set(labels[i].name + '-isOpen-alpha', false);
            }
            init();
        }
        if (e.target.classList.contains('legends-charts')) {
            var id = e.target.id;
            for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                if (labels[i].name === id) {
                    labels[i].isOpen = !labels[i].isOpen;
                } else {
                    labels[i].isOpen = false;
                }
                localStorageService.set(labels[i].name + '-isOpen-alpha', labels[i].isOpen);
            }
            init();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`$window` is a reference to the browser's `window` object. (See here for details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

`ng-click` causes a digest cycle through `$scope.$apply`. (Details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Relevant part:

> Listener directives, such as ng-click, register a listener with the
>   DOM. When the DOM listener fires, the directive executes the
>   associated expression and updates the view using the $apply() method.

Therefore, `$window.onclick` executes faster, because it doesn't cause a digest cycle.